# Schema creation giving error while installing SilverStripe

Tags: php, installation, silverstripe

I am trying to install SilverStripe CMS on my XAMPP setup. (Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8 ) 
In localhost/SilverStripe/install.php, I provided details of my database and clicked install SilverStripe.

The database gets created, while the schema creation gives error. (Error text below)

```
   Installing SilverStripe...
    I am now running through the installation steps (this should take about 30 seconds)
    If you receive a fatal error, refresh this page to continue the installation
    Setting up 'mysite/_config.php'...
    Setting up C:\xampp\htdocs\SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.7-rc1\mysite/_config.php
    Setting up '.htaccess' file...
    Setting up C:\xampp\htdocs\SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.7-rc1\.htaccess
    Building database schema...
     [Notice] Array to string conversion
     POST /SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.7-rc1/install.php
     Line 497 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.7-rc1\framework\model\Database.php

    Source
    488         $newTable = false;
    489         
    490         // backwards compatibility patch for pre 2.4 requireField() calls
    491         $spec_orig=$spec;
    492         
    493         if(!is_string($spec)) {
    494             $spec['parts']['name'] = $field;
    495             $spec_orig['parts']['name'] = $field;
    496             //Convert the $spec array into a database-specific string
    497             $spec=DB::getConn()->$spec['type']($spec['parts'], true);
    498         }
    499         
    500         // Collations didn't come in until MySQL 4.1.  Anything earlier will throw a syntax error if you try and use
    501         // collations.
    502         // TODO: move this to the MySQLDatabase file, or drop it altogether?
    503         if(!$this->supportsCollations()) {

Trace
SS_Database->requireField(File,ClassName,Array) 
DB.php:337
DB::requireField(File,ClassName,Array) 
Enum.php:83
Enum->requireField() 
Database.php:375
SS_Database->requireTable(File,Array,Array,1,Array,) 
DB.php:327
DB::requireTable(File,Array,Array,1,Array,) 
DataObject.php:3090
DataObject->requireTable() 
DatabaseAdmin.php:211
DatabaseAdmin->doBuild(1) 
install.php5:1415
Installer->install(Array) 
install.php5:277
include(C:\xampp\htdocs\SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.7-rc1\framework\dev\install\install.php5) 
install.php:26
include(C:\xampp\htdocs\SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.7-rc1\framework\dev\install\install.php) 
install.php:13
[Notice] Undefined property: MySQLDatabase::$Array
```

Any pointers on this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the version of SilverStripe you're trying to install. But from the line

> Setting up C:\xampp\htdocs\SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.7-rc1\mysite/_config.php

I'm guessing you're using version 3.1.7 which is outdated and not compatible with PHP 7.

When using PHP 7 you need to be using SilverStripe 3.6 or higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. Installing a higher version worked just fine.